# How to cryptographically verify web page requisites?

Tags: html, security, cdn, uri-scheme, subresource-integrity

**How to cryptographically verify web page requisites in HTML?**

For example, if I have some external resource like an image, a style sheet or (most importantly) a script on a (potentially untrusted) content delivery network, is it possible to force the client browser to cryptographically verify the hash of the downloaded resource before usage? Is there some HTML attribute or URL scheme for this or does one manually have to write some JavaScript to do it?

The rationale is that providing the hashes in HTML served over HTTPS provides an extra defence against compromised (or faulty) CDN-s.

Related questions on SO:

- [How secure are CDNs for delivering jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489344/how-secure-are-cdns-for-delivering-jquery)

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity, but I didn't use it and it is experimental at the moment.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex It sounds very interesting. Thanks! However I tend to think that an URI scheme might be a more universal solution.

Comment: Isn't that operating system dependent? Or do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055458/install-a-service-handler-for-uri-scheme-from-webpage ?

Comment: There is no “URL scheme” for this. What there is, is what @SideriteZackwehdex linked to – and now all you have to do, is wait for all browsers to implement that :-) And if this is so crucial for you that you don’t want to use it until all browsers implement it – well then I’d recommend you refrain from using CDNs until then, and host that stuff yourself instead. (Alternatively, you could of course load all those external resources via a script in the first place [assuming they are CORS-enabled] – and then perform that check yourself, and only embed them into the document if it passes.)

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex Some URI schemes might be OS dependent, but the most commonly used ones are probably all standardized by IETF. However, thank you for yet another relevant link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 23 June 2016 [Subresource Integrity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) is a W3C Recommendation which allows you to do just that (draft version [here](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/)). According to the [Implementation Report](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-subresource-integrity/wiki/Links) it is already implemented in Firefox 43 and Chrome 45.

A simple example using subresource integrity would be something like:

```
<script src="https://example.com/example.js"
    integrity="sha256-8OTC92xYkW7CWPJGhRvqCR0U1CR6L8PhhpRGGxgW4Ts="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It is also possible to specify multiple algorithm-hash pairs (called metadata) in integrity field, separated by whitespace and ignoring invalid data ([§3.3.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/#parse-metadata)). The client is expected to filter out the strongest metadata values ([§3.3.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/#get-the-strongest-metadata-from-set)), and compare the hash of the actual data to the hash values in set of the strongest metadata values ([§3.3.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/#does-response-match-metadatalist)) to determine whether the resource is valid. For example:

```
<script src="https://example.com/example.js"
    integrity="
       md5-kS7IA7LOSeSlQQaNSVq1cA==
       md5-pfZdWPRbfElkn7w8rizxpw==
       sha256-8OTC92xYkW7CWPJGhRvqCR0U1CR6L8PhhpRGGxgW4Ts=
       sha256-gx3NQgFlBqcbJoC6a/OLM/CHTcqDC7zTuJx3lGLzc38=
       sha384-pp598wskwELsVAzLvb+xViyFeHA4yIV0nB5Aji1i+jZkLNAHX6NR6CLiuKWROc2d
       sha384-BnYJFwkG74mEUWH4elpCm8d+RFIMDgjWWbAyaXAb8Oo//cHPOeYturyDHF/UcnUB"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If the client understands SHA256 and SHA384, but not MD5, then it tokenizes the value of the `integrity` attribute by whitespace and throws away the `md5-` metadata tokens as garbage. The client then determines that the strongest hashes in the metadata are SHA384 and compares their values to the SHA384 hash of the actual data received.